# Trying to start java application on tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have Java SpringBoot app and I want to run integration tests, so I want to start the application before any test. I have some beans which works when I run the app normally, those beans override some default beans and it works fine.

My logs when running the service normally:
`Overriding bean definition for bean 'myService' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: ...] with [Root bean: myBean]`

But when I try to run my integration test, the logs say this:
`Skipping bean definition for [where is my bean]: a definition for bean 'myService' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.`

Here is the test which starts the app:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)    
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class Test {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

Do somebody know how to set to override the default beans in my tests also?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set override beans for tests also, You can do this by making separate configuration class and define all the beans over there.

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

@Bean
public <Bean Class Name> <name of bean>()
{
    return new <Bean Class Name>();
}
}
```

Then on the test case you can use that configuration class as the Context Configuration.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
```

In this way all the beans can be initialize and use for test cases in a separate class.